# Add the values on the columns in R

Tags: r, graph

this is the code I used and I want to add values to the labels

```
ggplot(Duration_df,aes(x=factor(duration),y=sessions,fill=sessions)) + 
    xlab('Duration') + ylab('Sessions') +
    geom_bar(stat='identity',colour='black') + 
    scale_fill_gradient(low='red', high='green') + 
    ggtitle('Duration By Sessions') + 
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -35))
```

Comment: something like `+ geom_text(aes(label=sessions)`

Comment: What do you mean "add values on the labels"? Do you want values on the bars? *Post a representative sample of your data*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the label itself. In case you want to have the same value as `sessions` you can use the code below.

```
ggplot(Duration_df,aes(x=factor(duration),y=sessions,fill=sessions)) + 
    xlab('Duration') + ylab('Sessions') +
    geom_bar(stat='identity',colour='black') + 
    scale_fill_gradient(low='red', high='green') + 
    ggtitle('Duration By Sessions') + 
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -35)) + 
    geom_text(aes(label=sessions))
```

There are parameters as `hjust` or `vjust` for vertical and horizontal adjustment of the labels.

Comment: great tanks, if i want the values will shows in percent ?

Comment: Create a new column in `Duration_df` where you calculate the percentage. Then you can use `geom_text(aes(label=sprintf('%.2f%%', MY_PERCENT_COLUMN)))` Something like this should work.